# Add items from a String:Int dictionary to UITableView on iOS using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, uitableview

In my Swift-written iOS app, I have a `UITableView` with one `UILabel` in every row. Besides that, I also have a Dictionary of `[String:Int]` type.

I want each `UILabel` in the rows of `UITableView` to contain the String value from the dictionary. Each row will be as much times as the `Int` value represents.

For example, let's say I have this dictionary:

```
var dict: [String:Int] = ["apple": 2, "Banana": 3, "Orange": 7]
```

So in the `UITableView` I need to have 2 rows with `Apple` label in them, 3 rows with `Banana` label in them, and 7 rows with `Orange` label in them.

How can I accomplish that in the `tableView(cellForRowAt:)` method?

Comment: Brute Force method can be : 1. Take another array 2. Append your key corresponding to its value on right. 

Now you just need to use this array in any of Tableview Datasource and Delegate Methods.

Comment: why not using numberOfRowsInSections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need an array as data source to return the proper values for the delegate methods `numberOfRows` and `cellForRow`.

To convert the dictionary to a suitable array use something like this

```
let dict = ["apple": 2, "Banana": 3, "Orange": 7]

var fruit = [String]()

for key in dict.keys.sorted(by: {$0.lowercased() < $1.lowercased() }) {
    let value = dict[key]!
    for _ in 0..<value {
        fruit.append(key)
    }
} // result: ["apple", "apple", "Banana", "Banana", "Banana", "Orange", "Orange", "Orange", "Orange", "Orange", "Orange", "Orange"]
```